# Using Python context manager on command line without with

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I'm using a context manager written by Google that is intended for production use, but I would also like to use it on the command line interactively.

Normally, the context manager is used like this:

```
with some_context_manager():
    do_something()
```

This is tedious to do on the command line, especially when there are several statements to be done inside the with block.

Is there something sneaky you can do with the Python command line to be able to do something like this:

```
>>> start_context_manager(some_context_manager)
>>> do_something()
>>> stop_context_manager(some_context_manager)
```

I realize that kind of defeats the purpose of having a context manager in the first place, but it would make my life much easier.

In case the details are important, this is the context manager I am using:

```
from google.cloud import ndb
datastore_client = ndb.Client()
with datastore_client.context():
    do_something()
```

Comment: It probably depends on the specific context manager what would be best. Maybe `datastore_client` has a method that lets you do the same as when you use its `.context()` as a context manager? Or maybe you can just skip the context manager and use `do_something()` directly, like you can use a file like `f = open(...)` without necessarily using `with open(...) as f`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!